# Is the limit of a fundamental matrix solution necessarily a matrix solution?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Sometimes when trying to show the origin of a system of ODEs $x' = A(t)x$ is asymptotically stable, I'm given some assumptions that allows me to show, for instance, that $\det X(t) \to 0$ as $t\to \infty$. I'm not sure if this would allow me to conclude that $||X(t)||\to 0$ (which is equivalent to asymptotic stability), but since the only fundamental matrix with $\det = 0$ is the $0$ matrix, I was wondering if this perhaps implies that the limit of $X(t)$ is in fact the $0$ matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

First of all, a fundamental matrix of a system of ODE's is invertible.  It can't have determinant $0$, and can't be the $0$ matrix.

As for your question, consider the case $$A(t) = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & -2}$$ with fundamental matrix
$$ X(t) = \exp(A t) = \pmatrix{\exp(t) & 0\cr 0 & \exp(-2t)\cr}$$
Then $\det X(t) = \exp(-t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, but $\|X(t)\| = \exp(t)$ does not go to $0$.

Comment: Ah yes of course, probably didn't think that all the way through. And thanks for the counterexample as well.